# Why does Content-Length HTTP header field use a value other than the one given in Java code?

Tags: java, http, http-headers, http-content-length

I have a piece of Java code to transfer a byte array to HTTP server:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="
    + myBoundary);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 1024);
```

I used this code to transfer a byte array whose size is greater than 1024. It worked well. But the actual HTTP message (captured by [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) shows that the value of Content-Length is the actual size instead of 1024. Why?

I searched in [HTTP spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) but found no hint. I did not use any Transfer-Encoding or Transfer-coding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd guess that the `HttpURLConnection` will simply override the `Content-Length` header with the correct value, since it **knows** that lying about it is no good ;-)

And indeed: at the lines 535-550 of [`sun.net.www.protocol.HttpURLConnection`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/115020d6ea85/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java) the `Content-Length` is set if appropriate. This happens *after* the user-specified headers are set, so that value will be overwritten.

And it's right about that: if the amount of data you transfer does not match the claimed amount, then you'll only confuse the other end.

Checking [the source of `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/115020d6ea85/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java) it seems that there is a list of headers that are restricted and will silently be ignored when calling `setRequestProperty`. `Content-Length` is among that list. Unfortunately this seems to be undocumented (at least I couldn't find any documentation on this, only [a discussion of a related problem here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1997694&tstart=0)).

Googling for the Bug IDs (?) mentioned in [the ChangeSet that introduced this "functionality"](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/annotate/6e389e6349c9/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java) it seems that this change was introduces as a reaction to the security vulnerabilities [CVE-2010-3541](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2010-3541) and [CVE-2010-3573](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2010-3573) ([Redhat bug on this topic](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2010-3541)).

The restriction can manually be disabled by setting the System property `sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders` to `true` on JVM startup.

Comment: The value of `Content-Length` was hardcoded by mistake. What's surprising me is that it works. I want to know why.

Comment: Your guess sounds reasonable. But where to find the documentation on it?

Comment: @joachim-sauer: Great answer! But I have tested with sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true, and found the result is the same as before.

Comment: @wang: my long-ish analysis doesn't really apply here, since the `Content-Length` will be overwritten by the correct value anyway. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solved for me:

```
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(myString.getBytes().length);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(myString.getBytes().length));
```

"connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(myString.getBytes().length);" before set the Content-Length header.