# Domain not configured on this server

Tags: java, http, jsoup

I'm doing implementation of web-crawler and in that, I'm using `InetAddress` class to get ip addresses from domain names. I tried domain name, en.wikipedia.org and got ip `208.80.154.224`. Now i'm trying to fetch `page /wiki/Cricket` from that server using **jSoup** parser but getting error as below

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://208.80.154.224/wiki/Cricket
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:459)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
    at OtherClasses.TestDownloadJSoup.main(TestDownloadJSoup.java:30)
Java Result: 1
```

My code of fetching page is

```java
Connection con = Jsoup.connect("http://208.80.154.224/wiki/Cricket")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
                        .timeout(1000*5)
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com");
```

Wha should I do to resolve this 404 error and even I write this ip in browser it's giving domain not configured on this server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some server,can implement [Virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/), meaning that one server (one one IP address), can serve multiple domain name and decide which page to serve depending on the configuration.
You should add a [Host header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) in your query

```java
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true"); // this line is important to allow change in the Host header
Connection con = Jsoup.connect("http://208.80.154.224/wiki/Cricket")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
                    .timeout(1000*5)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .header("Host","en.wikipedia.org") // new entry here
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com");
```

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098440/105104) for more informations