# Setting "Host" header for Spring RestTemplate doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I want to send an HTTP request using [Spring RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), via the [exchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) method.

The third parameter is an instance of `HttpEntity`, which allows setting the headers/body of the request. I tried the following code snippet:

```java
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class Connector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Host", "www.example.com");
        headers.set("User-Agent", "whatever");


        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://httpbin.org/headers", HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<String>(null, headers), String.class);

        System.out.println(responseEntity.getBody());
    }
}
```

Notice that http://httpbin.org/headers is a simple HTTP Request & Response Service, which (in this case) returns HTTP headers.

The result of running the Java code is as follows:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/plain, */*", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "whatever"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `User-Agent` is set to what I wanted, but the `Host` is not.

> How can I set `Host` to the value I desire?

Comment: I'm not sure you can--it doesn't usually make sense to set the `Host` header to something different from the URI.

Comment: @chrylis: Thanks for the comment. In my use case, I'm writing a reverse proxy for some host H. The proxy is to be hosted at host H, and will contact the actual host H by IP. However, as the actual host H uses virtual hosting, I have to specify the host name H in my request (i.e., the request from the reverse proxy to the IP address).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this helps. I don't know if the underlying http call is made through HttpUrlConnection, but setting sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders to true might be worth trying.

See:

- [Can I override the Host header where using java's HttpUrlConnection class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648872/can-i-override-the-host-header-where-using-javas-httpurlconnection-class)
- [How to overwrite http-header "Host" in a HttpURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096987/how-to-overwrite-http-header-host-in-a-httpurlconnection)

Comment: Thank you very much; you saved my day! Setting `System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");` seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Beware! You've asked a question about Spring RestTemplate, but this fix is about Sun HttpURLConnection. If you configure RestTemplate with an Apache ConnectionFactory (which is a very good idea), this fix becomes irrelevant.

Comment: I followed this example to reconfigure RestTemplate and use Appache http client which can override the host header without any issues.
https://springframework.guru/using-resttemplate-with-apaches-httpclient/