# Is it possible to overide HttpRequestHeader Host spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, http-headers, http-host

I am trying to override the host of my `RequestHeader` based on some online resources it stated that setting `sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders` to true will enable the host to be edited as shown below:

```
 System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

 headers.set("Host", "my.dummy.test");

 MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
 map.add("appId", transactionInformation.getAppId());

 HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("https://xys/web/payments",
                request, String.class);
```

Basically I am trying to set the host to my.dummy.test.
However when i check the header after the post is carried out the host is not updated to my.dummy.test.

I am using spring boot starter parent (**2.3.0.RELEASE**) and java **JDK 14**.
Any advice how i can achieve it please?

Comment: see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223261/setting-host-header-for-spring-resttemplate-doesnt-work

Comment: thanks but System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true"); not working as suggested in the post