# How to set the Host header in JAX-RS / Apache CXF

Tags: ssh, jax-rs, cxf, cxf-client

I am trying to access a service over HTTPS but due to restrictive network settings I am trying to make the request through an ssh tunnel.

I create the tunnel with a command like:

> ssh -L 9443:my-service.com:443 sdt-jump-server

The service is only available via HTTPS, its hosted with a self-signed certificate, and it is behind a load-balancer that uses either the hostname or an explicit Host header to route incoming requests to the appropriate backend service.

I am able to invoke the endpoint from my local system using curl like

> curl -k -H 'Host: my-service.com' https://localhost:9443/path

However, when I try to use the CXF 3.1.4 implementation of JAX-RS to make the very same request, I can't seem to make it work. I configured a hostnameVerifier to allow the connection, downloaded the server's certificate, and added it to my truststore. Now I can connect, but it seemed like the load-balancer was not honoring the Host header that I'm trying to set.

I was lost for a bit until I set `-Djavax.net.debug` and saw that the Host header being passed was actually `localhost` and not the value I set. How to make CXF honor the Host header I'm setting instead of using the value from the URL of the WebTarget?!

Comment: Are you using WebClient or the standardized JAX-RS client? Btw. please use at least latest 3.1.x version, 3.1.4 is outdated.

Comment: I'm using the standardized client (ClientBuilder.newBuilder()) and I'm setting the header with something like this:  `client.target("https://localhost:9443/").path("path").request(mimeType).header("Host","my-service.com")`

Comment: Also, updating to 3.1.15 didn't seem to make a difference for this particular behavior.  Maybe its the ssh tunnel rewriting the Host header and not CXF?  But would `javax.net.debug=all` pick it up in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CXF uses HttpUrlConnection, so you need to set a system property programmatically

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true")
```

or at startup:

```
-Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true
```

See also [How to overwrite http-header "Host" in a HttpURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096987/how-to-overwrite-http-header-host-in-a-httpurlconnection/9098440)