# fiddler: how to disable overwrite Header Host

Tags: http, fiddler, host

When using Fiddler, it pops up an alert dialog.

```
Fiddler has detected a protocol violation in session #14.

The Request's Host header did not match the URL's host component.

URL Host:   proxy.music.pp.com
Header Host:    119.147.22.41
```

And it shows that Fiddler changed HTTP Header's host to "proxy.music.pp.com", is there any way to disable Fiddler changing it?

Comment: What client is generating this (illegal) traffic?

Answer (score 8):

From my [book](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/):

**Swap the Host Header**

When Fiddler gets a request whose URL doesn’t match its Host header, the original Host value is stored in the session flag `X-Original-Host` and then the `Host` value is replaced with the host parsed from the URL. The following script, placed inside your FiddlerScript's `BeforeRequest` function, reverses behavior by routing the request to the host specified by the original Host header.

```
if (oSession.BitFlags & SessionFlags.ProtocolViolationInRequest) 
{
  var sOverride = oSession["X-Original-Host"];
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sOverride)) 
  {
    oSession["X-overrideHost"] = sOverride;
    oSession["ui-backcolor"] = "yellow";

    // Be sure to bypass the gateway, otherwise overrideHost doesn't work
    oSession.bypassGateway = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Newest version of Fiddler (v5.0.20182.28034, but I don't know how long ago this changed) no longer seems to put anything into the `X-Original-Host` session flag so this solution doesn't work any more.

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm using the Composer feature? How do I make the composer send the request to the IP address of "g2-prod-by3-003-sb.servicebus.windows.net" but use the host header "dstucki-relay.servicebus.windows.net"? When I try this it always uses the Host header value to resolve to the IP address.
https://snag.gy/SiQ0OA.jpg (Notice the IP address the TCP traffic goes to is that of example2.com).

Comment: Ah, for the Composer, try creating a fake `Fiddler-Host: example.com` header. The Composer will convert this to an X-OverrideHost flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with rules.

Go into Customize rules, and find the function: `OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session)`

Then add the following as the last line of that function:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("proxy.music.pp.com")) { oSession.host = "119.147.22.41"; }
```

Comment: It will still show the error of protocol violation, but it will use the ip address as the http header host.

Comment: This also changes the host name the request is sent to. The question was about preventing Fiddler from overriding the Host header.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what the "url host" was supposed to be - I mean, normally, there is only the Host header in HTTP.

Looking closer, it appears that this violation occurs for an initial proxy "setup" request, which looks like this:

```
 CONNECT targaryen:45633 HTTP/1.1
 Host: targaryen
```

This is where the error makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get what I needed for the existing answers, but Eric Law's answer gave me what I needed to fix my issue.  I was having a problem where I was calling a web server by IP address, and I had to add a Host header to get the right endpoint.  Fiddler was changing the Host header to the IP address I was calling and removing my Host header value, which caused the call to fail.  I added a line to Eric's script to solve this.  I put the rule into *OnBeforeRequest* in the Fiddler Rules Script.

```
 if (oSession.BitFlags & SessionFlags.ProtocolViolationInRequest) 
    {
        var sOverride = oSession["X-Original-Host"];

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sOverride)) 
        {
            oSession["X-overrideHost"] = sOverride;
            oSession["ui-backcolor"] = "yellow";
            oSession.oRequest["Host"] = sOverride;

            // Be sure to bypass the gateway, otherwise overrideHost doesn't work
            oSession.bypassGateway = true;
        }
    }
```

**Took this Error:**
[image: 404 error]
[image: Bad Request]

**And changed it to this:**
[image: 200 Response]
[image: Good Request]

Comment: For those who may find this trying to try down in Java why the Host header won't stay set when using an IP address, It seems the standards group decided to be compliant they must match, and HttpURLConnection was replacing my Host header with it's own.  More information can be found about this problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648872/can-i-override-the-host-header-where-using-javas-httpurlconnection-class .  Short answer is System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true") to override that behavior.