# As I can intercept a TCP packet in real time?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, packet

Hello that such I need your help
I happen to intercept all TCP packets that are sent by filtering my team, I want to modify a http header that includes the host "example.com" and replace "localhost".

They know of any example in C#?  Thank you

For example the following header

```
GET / tutorials / other / top-20-mysql-best-practices / HTTP / 1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: App 2.0
Accept: text / html, application / xhtml + xml, application / xml; q = 0.9, * / *; q = 0.8
Accept-Language: en-us, en; q = 0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Replace with:

```
GET / tutorials / other / top-20-mysql-best-practices / HTTP / 1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: App 2.0
Accept: text / html, application / xhtml + xml, application / xml; q = 0.9, * / *; q = 0.8
Accept-Language: en-us, en; q = 0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Comment: Create a HTTP proxy and direct all traffic through it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863037/fiddler-how-to-disable-overwrite-header-host