# Browse IIS website with domain binding on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8

I have two websites on local IIS (ver 8):

```
\Website1 (Binding: http:*:80:)
  Index.html
\Website2 (http:*:80:anotherwebsite.com)
  Index.html
```

Is there a way to browse locally IIS website **Website2**?
Browsing *anotherwebsite.com* is wrong - DNS will point me to the "public" *anotherwebsite.com*. Browsing **localhost/anotherwebsite.com** is also wrong - this will browse **Website1**.

I cannot change hosts file - this change has to be quick and easy (used for deployment heartbeat). I also don't want to add another binding (possible solution would be to add binding **http:*:123:** to **Website2** and browse **localhost:123**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to get your web-browser to connect to `localhost` but to spoof the `Host` header. Fortunately there are Chrome and Firefox extensions to do this. Search online for "chrome extension spoof host-header" (or Firefox). There are no extensions yet available for MS Edge.

Another option is to use the venerable Fiddler tool, which is a local HTTP proxy that works on every web-browser and lets you change any outgoing headers too: [fiddler: how to disable overwrite Header Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863037/fiddler-how-to-disable-overwrite-header-host)

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. If somebody is wondering if just setting HttpWebRequest.Host works - yes it does.