# How to avoid fiddler discard my header: host?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, fiddler, host

This is my C# code:

```
var url = "http://10.2.0.2/api";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Referer = url;
request.Host = "wwww.abc.com";
request.Accept = "*/*";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

while I run the code, and open fiddler to capture request,
I found fiddler discard header: Host,
so my IIS returned an error!

How did I avoid it?
Why fiddler discards Host but keep other headers?

Question: [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863037/fiddler-how-to-disable-overwrite-header-host)

was header be changed, my question was header be discard.

I found my solution, open FiddlerScript, and add these script:

```
     static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
            var sOverride = oSession["X-Original-Host"];
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sOverride)) 
            {
                oSession.oRequest.headers["Host"] = sOverride;
            }
```

Comment: What happens when you close Fiddler and send a request?

Comment: I found this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863037/fiddler-how-to-disable-overwrite-header-host,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fiddler: how to disable overwrite Header Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863037/fiddler-how-to-disable-overwrite-header-host)