# Azure Storage Service REST APIs: Create Container

Tags: java, rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Getting the below error while making a call to Create Container.

> Response Code : 411 Response Message : Length Required

```
String stringToSign = "PUT\n\n\n\n0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-version:" + "2014-02-14\n" + "/" + storageAccount + "/"+ "container-create-test"+"\nrestype:container"+"\ntimeout:60";
```

Java code snippet.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod(vMethod);
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeader);
connection.addRequestProperty("x-ms-date", date);
connection.addRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2014-02-14");
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the format of StringToSign.

> 411 Response Message : Length Required

This error means you don't add `Content-Length:0` header in your http request.

**Update**

As you work with HttpURLConnection in Java, `Content-Length` header can't be set manually by default, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056125/why-does-content-length-http-header-field-use-a-value-other-than-the-one-given-i).

In case of other trouble, here's the complete sample for you to refer.

```
public static void putContainer() throws Exception {
    // Account info
    String accountName = "accountName";
    String accountKey = "accountKey";

    // Request Uri and Method
    String containerName = "containerName";
    String requestUri = "https://"+accountName+".blob.core.windows.net/"+containerName+"?restype=container&timeout=60";
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(requestUri)).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");

    // Request Headers
    // 1. x-ms-version, recommend to use the latest version if possible
    String serviceVersion = "2018-03-28";
    // 2. x-ms-date
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
    // 3. Authorization
    String authKeyFormat = "SharedKey";
    String caHeader = "x-ms-date:"+date+"\nx-ms-version:"+serviceVersion+"\n";
    String caResource = "/"+accountName+"/"+containerName+"\nrestype:container\ntimeout:60";
    String signStr = "PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"+caHeader+caResource;
    String authorization = getAuthorization(accountName, authKeyFormat, signStr, accountKey);

    // Send request
    connection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", serviceVersion);
    connection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date",date);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
    // Send 0 byte, code sets Content-Length:0 automatically
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(0);

    System.out.println("Response message : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
    System.out.println("Response code : " + connection.getResponseCode());
}

private static String getAuthorization(String accountName, String authKeyFormat, String signStr, String accountKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException {

    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(accountKey), "HmacSHA256");
    Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
    String signature = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256HMAC.doFinal(signStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    return authKeyFormat+" "+accountName+":"+signature;
}
```

Comment: @TechPassionate Have added the code sample(including your former question), you could have a try. If you are still baffled, feel free to ask. If those samples do work for you, you could accept them as answers for others to refer. Besides, if there's no specific requirement, [storage sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) is always preferred.

Comment: I see an issue with Create Lease: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100823/azure-storage-service-rest-apis-create-lease

Comment: @JerryLiu Thank you very much! I added the code `connection.setDoOutput(true); connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(0);`. It worked!