# Why are some of the headers restricted in HttpURLConnection after JDK 1.6?

Tags: java, http, https, header, httpurlconnection

**Need a deeper understanding on this topic**.

I tried to lookup for specific reasons in documentations for the restricted headers but couldn't find one.

Here is a list of restricted headers:

`Accept-Charset`
`Accept-Encoding`
`Access-Control-Request-Headers`
`Access-Control-Request-Method`
`Connection`
`Content-Length`
`Cookie`
`Cookie2`
`Date`
`DNT`
`Expect`
`Host`
`Keep-Alive`
`Origin`
`Referer`
`TE`
`Trailer`
`Transfer-Encoding`
`Upgrade`
`Via`

**refer**: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/31bc1a681b51/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#l186

To override these it is required to set **sun.net.http.allowrestrictedheaders** to **true** at JVM startup or use
**System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true")**

It is said that it has been disabled as part of a security-fix.

**I want to understand what security risk might have pulled up and how was making headers forbidden to use was a solution to that, keeping in mind you still can override the headers.**

**links to refer:**

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name

[Why does Content-Length HTTP header field use a value other than the one given in Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056125/why-does-content-length-http-header-field-use-a-value-other-than-the-one-given-i/6056230#6056230)

[Can I override the Host header where using java's HttpUrlConnection class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648872/can-i-override-the-host-header-where-using-javas-httpurlconnection-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [first link](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name) says in a note (green text):

> These are forbidden so the **user agent remains in full control** over them

It's to prevent spoofing by malicious javascript code in Web Browsers.

Since the Java code is not a Web Browser, only some of them are restricted in Java, as the link to the source code shows.

The headers that are still restricted are controlled directly by the `HttpURLConnection` class, and there should be no need to spoof the values, so leaving them restricted should not be an issue.